# UIToolbar and UIImageView not showing up in Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uitoolbar

In the Big Nerd Ranch, iOS Programming guide (3rd ed.) the 12th chapter is "Camera".

In that, they add a `UIToolbar` object in the XIB file and then a camera `barbuttonitem`. We had to add a `UIImageView` in the center as well with view modes `Aspect Fit`.

I followed these instructions as is and then made the necessary connections and added a target-action method from the camera button to the file's owner(`DetailViewController`).

**Everything seems to be fine until I run the code in the simulator wherein it doesn't show the added `UIImageView` and the `UIToolbar`. Every other object that was added prior to those, appear fine(the Labels and TextFields).**

The code contains a `navigationController` which has a `rootViewController` (`ItemsViewController`). So when I select an item in the ItemsViewController's tableview (since `ItemsViewController` is a `TableViewController`) a new `viewController` gets pushed on the `UINavigationController's` stack which would be `DetailViewController`.

Now `DetailViewController.xib` is where all the objects including the **toolbar and the imageview (the 2 things that are having issues appearing)** have been configured and connected.

I haven't included **ItemsViewController's** implementation. Just **DetailViewController's**.

Here's the code:

DetailViewController.h

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     @class BNRItem;
     @interface DetailViewController :     UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
     {
         __weak IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
         __weak IBOutlet UITextField *serialNumberField;
         __weak IBOutlet UITextField *valueField;
         __weak IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
         __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

     }
     @property BNRItem *item; 
     - (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender;
     @end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
     #import "DetailViewController.h"
     #import "BNRItem.h"
     @interface DetailViewController ()

     @end

     @implementation DetailViewController

     -(void)viewDidLoad{
          NSLog(@"DetailsView loaded");
          [super viewDidLoad];
          [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];    
      }

     -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
         NSLog(@"DetailsView appearing");
         [nameField setText:[_item itemName]];
         [serialNumberField setText:[_item serialNumber]];
         [valueField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[_item valueInDollars]]];

         NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
         [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

         [dateLabel setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:_item->dateCreated]];
       }

      -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
           NSLog(@"DetailsView disappearing");
           [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

          //Clear First Responder
          [self.view endEditing:YES];

          //Save changes to the item.
          [_item setItemName:[nameField text]];
          [_item setSerialNumber:[serialNumberField text]];
          [_item setValueInDollars:[[valueField text] intValue]];

      }

      -(void)setItem:(BNRItem *)item{
        _item= item;
        [self.navigationItem setTitle:[_item itemName]];
      } 
      - (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
         UIImagePickerController *imagePicker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

             if ([UIImagePickerController   isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
               NSLog(@"Yes. The Camera is available ");
               [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
             }
             else{
               NSLog(@"The Camera isn't available.Try thru the Photo Library");
               [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
             }
             [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
             [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` in your implementation method, as is said in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_89).

Comment: Yeah i missed that one out..But i've done it now and run the simulator. No change.. The UIToolbar and UIImageView are still not appearing.The first view that i'm supposed to see ItemViewController's view which has a **navBar**. And its a tableView, when i select anyone of the tableViewCells i will be taken to DetailViewController's view where all the subviews such as Textfields,labels and a navBar with a barButtonItem is located. Now additionally i had also added a toolbar with a camera button and separate imageView in the center. These two new additions in the XIB aren't showing up.

Comment: Bear in mind that ItemsViewController is a rootViewController of the NavigationBar. And DetailsViewController is pushed onto the NavController's stack when a row in the ItemsViewController's tableView is selected.

Answer (score 0):

use 4 inch simulator, this is requested by the auther in the first chapters.
as u move to the chapters related to constrain u will be able to solve the 3.5 inch simulator